# Runtime Error (NZEC) - Python / Codechef

Tags: python

I'm getting started with Codechef. I submitted following code in python to solve [this question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST).

The code below works fine with codechef's online (python) IDE as well as my local IDE. But, when I submit it on codechef, it results in Runtime Error (NZEC). Can someone explain to me the reason behind this?

```
withdrawCash = int(input())
totalCash = int(input())
if withdrawCash < totalCash and withdrawCash % 5 is 0:
    totalCash = (totalCash - withdrawCash) - 0.5
    print(totalCash)
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022097/nzec-runtime-error-in-python) might help because I've been there and got rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem supplies both the inputs in a single line. Your code waits for input in 2 lines. Change it to:

```
withdrawCash,totalCash = map(int,raw_input.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

NZEC (Non Zero Exit Code) occurs when your code doesn't return zero on exit. It can happen due to a number of reasons, but if splitting the input doesn't solve the problem, add an exception for `EOFerror`. Just write:

```
try:
    withdrawCash = int(input().split())  # raw_input in the case of Python 2
except EOFerror: 
    print ("exit") # this is jst a pseudo statement `
```

**Use indentation properly.** I am currently using an android app of stack exchange in which writing code is not so easy. `codechef` is pretty poor when it comes to Python. Switch to any other lang for CP.

Answer (score 0):

Try directly submitting the code without running it on Codechef ide because it with me also it showed the same but when I submitted directly I got submitted successfully. so Directly submit your code.

Comment: It's nice of you to offer some advice, but note that this question from 2015 has an accepted answer. Furthermore, the accepted answer provided an actual answer rather than a workaround.