# NZEC - Runtime Error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I stated practicing CodeChef recently and every program I submit gives me NZEC runtime error.
Even a simple program to add two numbers n number of time like:

```
for _ in xrange(input()):
      print input()+input()
```

and a program to for printing bank balance

```
withdraw = input()
balance = input()
if withdraw % 5 == 0 and (balance - withdraw - 0.5)>0:
      f = balance - withdraw - 0.5
      print "%0.2f" %f
else:
     print "%0.2f" %balance
```

gives the same error.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

PS: I'm using python IDLE and PyCharm. Both gave proper outputs.
I got error in CodeChef and www.ideone.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe nobody saw this post or nobody has tried to answer this, I tried a lot and found the answer for this. I'm answering my own question for those who might have the same problem I had.
When we submit codes online, they give the input as a text file. Hence the inputs are in a single line.

I tried the same program I submitted in the question in [Hackerrank](http://www.hackerrank.com) and gave the custom inputs from [CodeChef's](http://www.codechef.com) site and found that the error was that the inputs were on the same line.
I changed my code to:

```
t = input()
while(t):
num = raw_input().split()
n = int(num[0])
k = int(num[1])
a = raw_input().split()
a = [float(a[x]) for x in xrange(n)]
if(n>2*k):
    while(k):
        a.remove(max(a))
        a.remove(min(a))
        k-=1
    print '%.06f' %(sum(a)/len(a))
t-=1
```

Works fine now didn't get full marks though.
I hope some newbie who might face the same problem I did finds this useful.